# Subquery: Help Correct Syntax Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work. Using Oracle and getting the following error: ORA-00933.

```
SELECT MBR_ID
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE SUBSTR(COMM_PLAN_ID,1,10) IN ('918', '944', '955')
AND COMM_PLAN_ID <>'99999'
AND DATE_OF_SVC BETWEEN '20160101' AND 20160630'
AND CLAIM_STATUS = '1'
(SELECT MBR_ID, COUNT (CLAIM_IDENT)
FROM RIDE
WHERE RUNDATE = 20161202
AND MOP_ADJ_PD_CLAIMS > 90000
```

Comment: Your query is missing a single quote on the 5th line.

Comment: You also, probably, need an `AND` before `(SELECT`

Comment: There isn't any condition column for subquery and closing bracket also missing..... in all the query is messed up and won't get any help so please review the code then ask again for any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MBR_ID FROM CLAIMS
WHERE SUBSTR(COMM_PLAN_ID,1,10) IN ('918', '944', '955') AND COMM_PLAN_ID    
<>'99999' AND DATE_OF_SVC BETWEEN '20160101' AND 20160630 AND CLAIM_STATUS =     
'1' AND EXISTS 
(
  SELECT MBR_ID, COUNT (CLAIM_IDENT)
  FROM RIDE
  WHERE RUNDATE = 20161202
  AND MOP_ADJ_PD_CLAIMS > 90000  AND RIDE.MBR_ID = CLAIMS.MBR_ID
 )
```